# How can an offline HTML/JavaScript website be made secure?

Tags: javascript, html, security, encryption

How can an offline website ([zip, MHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260058/whats-the-best-file-format-for-saving-complete-web-pages-images-etc-in-a), [SingleFile](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/singlefile/mpiodijhokgodhhofbcjdecpffjipkle?hl=en)) be made secure?  Are there techniques (obfuscating, encrypting) or anything within the specs of HTML or JavaScript (ECMAScript) that would allow for an offline website to be *secure on its own*?

By "secure" I mean that if a user has a local copy of the website, they may not still have access to the contents without a password. Imagine a level of security approximating that which is used in PDF documents.

Comment: Here's the originating idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29778763/what-technical-things-can-be-done-with-pdf-but-not-an-html-website

Comment: For regular user it's ok, but  if someone really wants to decrypt your data the will manage to do it.

Comment: @PedroLobito - I understand that anyone with a local copy of the site can eventually get access, I would only be looking for a level of protection roughly equal to that being used in common PDF documents.

Comment: @Luke How does user initially obtain "a local copy of the website" ?

Comment: Why would the user have a local copy? Are they opening the local copy with their browser? How do they specify the decryption password if they do open their local file?

Comment: @guest271314 -- Is that important? I don't have a set distribution method in mind -- they would download it, get it in an email, or from a USB drive.

Comment: @Luke Was not certain if user obtained website independently ; with expected result that user could not then access file.

Answer (score 1):

You may use an offline js function (https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#Ciphers here are some algorithms that will do) to encrypt all the data, and ask for a password to decrypt it.
Note that you shouldn't store the correct password, but instead check if it is correct by decrypting with the password given by the user a known message (encrypt "hello world" with the correct password, and then check if the password given by the user works).

Answer (score 0):

Yes; you can encrypt the data, then decrypt it in Javascript.

Note that any user with the encryption will always have full access to the data.

Comment: Can you provide more details on *how* this might be done?

Comment: Use AES for encryption and PBKDFv2 for key derivation.